# Modal is not working with react js, on click of edit button

Tags: reactjs

I am new here in react js, I want to open modal on click of edit button, but it gives me error `'App' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef`, Can anyone please help why i am getting that error ? On click of edit button it is call `editTask` function, and from that function it call `toggleModal()`function here i have added my full code here, anyhelp will be really appreciated

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import './modal.js';    

class PalladiumHub extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (<tr>
      <td>{this.props.keyuser}</td>
      <td>{this.props.name.name}</td>
      <td><button type="button" onClick={(e) => { this.props.editTask(this.props.index) }} >Edit</button><button onClick={(e) => { this.props.deleteTask(this.props.index) }}>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    )
  }
} //{} {}

class CallCRUD extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this);
    this.editTask = this.editTask.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
      isOpen: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {

          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  toggleModal() {
      return <App openModal = {this.openModal} />; 
  }


  deleteTask(index) {
    alert(index);
    console.log(index);
    //return false;
    let tasks = this.state.items;

    tasks.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      items: tasks
    })
  }

  editTask(index) {
    this.toggleModal();
    console.log(index);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.items);
    return (<table border="1"> <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Action</th></tr> {
      this.state.items.map((data, index) => {
        //return console.log(data.id);
        return <PalladiumHub name={data} keyuser={data.id} index={index} key={index} deleteTask={this.deleteTask} editTask={this.editTask} />
      })

    }
    </table>
    );
  }


}


ReactDOM.render(
  <CallCRUD />, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

modal.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Modal from 'react-modal';  

const customStyles = {
  content : {
    top                   : '50%',
    left                  : '50%',
    right                 : 'auto',
    bottom                : 'auto',
    marginRight           : '-50%',
    transform             : 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
  }
};

// Make sure to bind modal to your appElement (http://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/accessibility/)
//Modal.setAppElement('#root')

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: false
    };

    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.afterOpenModal = this.afterOpenModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
  }

  openModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
  }

  afterOpenModal() {
    // references are now sync'd and can be accessed.
    this.subtitle.style.color = '#f00';
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
          onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
          onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
          style={customStyles}
          contentLabel="Example Modal"
        >

          <h2 ref={subtitle => this.subtitle = subtitle}>Hello</h2>
          <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
          <div>I am a modal</div>
          <form>
            <input />
            <button>tab navigation</button>
            <button>stays</button>
            <button>inside</button>
            <button>the modal</button>
          </form>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks likes you're initating <App openModal = {this.openModal} />. But you never imported App into that file.

Comment: I have imported import './modal.js'; in index.js files

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you dont have App imported into your PalladiumHub and CallCRUD file. It's just saying that Reacy doesnt know where App is coming from.

Comment: At the top of your PalladiumHub component with the rest of your imports you must import your App component if you want it to be usable on that page. The import would look something like 

    `import App from "./path/to/App"`

Comment: Thanks, now i am not getting that error, but modal is not working this function toggleModal() {
      return <App openModal = {this.openModal} />; 
  }

Comment: Can you please tell me how to call that function ?